# Single marble stacking operation that fills out a 3-dimensional space?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, combinatorial-geometry

My question is:

> Is there a way to stack marbles by using only a single one-marble stacking operation such that an infinite 3-dimensional stack is constructed?

For example:

In 1-dimension one can start with a stack such as

```
-o-o-o-o
```

and by adding a marble `-o` infinitely, with a single operation of attaching it from the right, one can construct an infinite 1-dimensional stack.

In 2-dimensions, one can start with a stack such as

```
 o-o-o-o-o-o
/| | | | | |
 o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
/| | | | | | | | | | | | |/
 o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
/| | | | | | | | | | | | |/
 o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
/| | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

where the last marble on the right in each row is connected to the first marble on the left one row higher. With this, the single operation of adding a marble with two connections:

```
-o
 |
```

can be used infinitely to construct an infinite homogeneous 2-dimensional stack of marbles. (Note that there are no edge effects as we pass from one row to the next. The rows themselves are an artifact of the visualization. After adding one marble to the stack above, we can rearrange our viewpoint by pushing all marbles one position to the left and arrive at the original viewpoint, but the stack is now one marble longer.)

Can something similar be done for a three-dimensional stack as well? If yes, how does the stack and the stacking operation look like?

Comment: I would look at the Cantor Pairing function (or any other pairing function). You can get a bijection from $\mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ as follows. If $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the normal pairing function, then $g:\mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ could be $g(a,b,c) = f(f(a,b),c)$. Since this is a bijection, if you number the one-dimensional marbles, the inverse of this function will tell you where the marble will wind up in 3 dimensions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in 2D that the last marble on the right is connected to the first marble on the left one row higher.  It seems like the marbles are only connected to four neighbors each.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: @RossMillikan That's right, each marble is connected to four neighbors: left, up, down, and right. The 'right' neighbor of each last marble on the right in each row is the first marble on the left one row higher.

Comment: But then you don't have an infinite grid in the horizontal direction if you can talk of the last marble in each direction.

Comment: @RossMillikan That is correct! The grid is only infinite in up-down-direction, and we can vary the length in the left-right-direction. We can then consider the limit of infinite length in the left-right-direction as well, if desired.

Comment: @Kagaratsch I don't think you can consider the 'limit of infinite length' because the operations you're doing aren't continuous with respect to the limit. (This is analagous to the 'add two marbles, remove the smallest' paradox of limits.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Fair enough, but I think in this case the problem is a bit simpler. Imagine a square sheet of stacked marbles with connections left, up, down, right. A priori, there is no restriction on how tall and wide that sheet can be. Then one can consider connecting the upper boundary of the sheet with the lower, and left boundary with the right -- into a torus. this can be done either matching each row with itself, or introducing a twist by connecting right end of rows with left end of rows one step up. Finally, there is an infinite sequence of different sizes of such tori.

Comment: Woudn't a spiral pattern work better for a 2-d stack? That could be extended to a 3-D stack with the same trick you used.

Comment: @Kagaratsch That illustrates the problem nicely, though. For instance, a torus of any size, either continuous or discrete, isn't _simply connected_ — there are 'essential' loops that can't be shrunk down to nothing. But the plane is, so the topology is discontinuous across that limiting process.

Comment: That said, you say 'the single operation', but it really isn't; while locally every node (past a certain point) looks like every other node, there's still a choice that's made at some point to 'close the loop', and that choice will distinguish the marbles before that point from the marbles after.

Comment: @Aretino that sounds interesting! Perhaps you could expand a little on that by posting an answer? Maybe draw a picture to visualize what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer a slightly different mathematical footing for this question that gives it both a positive (locally) and a negative (globally) answer.

One useful model for thinking about structures like this is the notion of a *Cayley graph* for (a presentation of) a group; the nodes of the graph are the elements of the group, and the links between nodes represent the generators of the presentation. For instance, the 'classic' presentation of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ is literally just $\langle a\rangle$; the group has a single generator, and there are no relations between any of the elements. The elements are all of the form $a^n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and we associate the element $a^n$ with the number $n$. The Cayley graph for this presentation is just the (doubly infinite) line of nodes. The standard presentation of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is $\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle$; two generators that commute with each other, with the group elements of the form $a^mb^n$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The Cayley graph for this presentation is the infinite two-dimensional graph, with each node $a^mb^n$ connected to the nodes $a^{m\pm1}b^n$ and $a^mb^{n\pm1}$; the relation $ab=ba$ corresponds to the fact that starting from the node $a^mb^n$ and taking an $a$-step to $a^{m+1}b^n$ and then a $b$-step to $a^{m+1}b^{n+1}$ — that is, going along the bottom and right edges of a square — brings you to the same place as taking a $b$-step and then an $a$-step. From this perspective, the squares in the Cayley graph represent the commutativity of the generators.

Cayley graphs automatically give the sort of 'uniformity' that you're looking for, because the neighborhood around each node of the graph is identical to the neighborhood around any other node.

Now, we can think of your construction as a Cayley graph for a different presentation of the group $\mathbb{Z}$. The fact that the group is $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to your notion of adding elements 'one by one' — there's a single chain through the entire structure that can be followed. But when you connect e.g. the seventh element in the string back to the first, you're introducing a second generator $b$ (which represents the 'y connection'), and a relation of the form $b=a^7$ (seven steps 'around' the ring is equivalent to one step 'up'). This means that the Cayley graph for $\mathbb{Z}$ with the presentation $\langle a,b\mid b=a^7\rangle$ is a cylinder, with a chain of elements spiraling up the cylinder. The idea that this is a 'two-dimensional' grid comes from the fact that there are two generators; and in fact, it's 'locally indistinguishable' from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ in any patch that doesn't go so far as to actually show the 'wrap' represented by the $b=a^7$ relation (i.e., any strip that's less than seven elements wide).  Note that we could add a relation of the form $ab=ba$ to make the squares explicit, but we actually get this 'for free'; it's already implied by the relation $b=a^7$. By taking larger and larger values of $7$, you can make this local indistinguishability happen over a larger and larger patch.

From this perspective, what you're looking for is a presentation of $\mathbb{Z}$ that's locally indistinguishable from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$; every node in the Cayley graph will have two links each along three different axes, that form commuting cubes. This corresponds to the presentation $\langle a,b,c\mid ab=ba, ac=ca, bc=cb\rangle$ for $\mathbb{Z}^3$. Now, similarly to how we wrapped the cylinder by adding a relation $b=a^n$, we can consider adding two distinct relations; one for $b=a^m$ will mean that every $m$ steps in the 'x' direction ($a$), we'll take one 'y' step ($b$). Likewise, a relation $c=b^n$ will mean that every $n$ steps in the 'y' direction ($b$), we'll take one 'z' step ($c$). Since $b^n=(a^m)^n=a^{(mn)}$, every $mn$ 'x' steps will also correspond to that one 'z' step. Essentially, this corresponds to filling in the rows of an $m\times n$ grid, one by one; the end of one row is linked to the start of the next exactly analagous to the 2d case, but then after we've done $n$ rows' worth of this, we wrap again, back to the start of the grid, one level higher (the 'z' step). So a presentation of the form $\langle a,b,c\mid b=a^m, c=b^n\rangle$ gives a 3d analog of your cylindrical spiral; as long as your patch is smaller than $m\times n$, you won't have any links that let you distinguish it from a 'real' $\mathbb{Z}^3$ grid (that is, these relations are minimal in that sense; a single $b$ step can't be represented with fewer than $m$ $a$ steps, and a single $c$ step can't be represented with fewer than $n$ $b$ steps, or with any combination of $a$ and $b$ steps smaller than that).

So given this, you can take $m$ and $n$ as large as you want, and get presentations of $\mathbb{Z}$ that look locally like $\mathbb{Z}^3$ for larger and larger ranges of locality; and of course, there's nothing that restricts us to three dimensions here, so you can get a similar 'locally $\mathbb{Z}^d$' presentation for $\mathbb{Z}$ for any dimension $d$. But these presentations always *have* to be local; there will always have to be some loop in your structure. This is because the groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (and $\mathbb{Z}^3$, etc.) are all distinct from each other (which is a very nontrivial statement!), and two distinct groups will *always* have distinct Cayley graphs, whatever presentation you give them.

Comment: (There are also questions about being able to embed these graphs in space; for instance, the cylindrical spiral corresponding to $\langle a,b\mid b=a^n\rangle$ can be embedded 'uniformly' in 3d, but not really in 2d, despite its locally 2d nature. Similarly, the toroidal spiral of $\langle a,b,c\mid b=a^m, c=b^n\rangle$ can be embedded uniformly in 4d, but not in 3d, despite the locally 3d nature of it.)

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough discussion, I think that gets close to the issue I'm trying to understand. You point out that the uniform embedding works only in one dimension higher, but one could still use a non-uniform embedding by using identifications at the edges, like the 2d example in my question. I wonder how such a 3d example would look like explicitly, using identifications at the edges? Basically, taking a 3d uniform stack of marbles with 6 connections each, how would one glue the boundaries to achieve constructibility from a single operation that adds a marble with 3 connections?

Comment: @Kagaratsch Take a rectangular grid, connect the right hand edge to the left hand edge offset by one, and then connect the top edge to the bottom edge offset by 1. If you consider the 2d case (and use a 'width' of 7, as in my examples), then your two backwards connections from marble $n$ are to marbles $n-1$ and $n-7$; for the 3d case, with a 7x7 width-height, the backwards connections from marble $n$ would be to marbles $n-1$, $n-7$, and $n-49$.

Comment: I understand that in the 2d torus example the topology has a hole. That's OK with me, I'm also happy with just an infinite cylinder, or even a finite cylinder. While the first row that makes the cylinder base will have different construction rules from the second and later rows, what I mostly am interested in is that its extension can proceed infinitely by a single operation, once the base is given. The construction of the base is kind of like a boundary effect, which I'm neglecting.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers on the size 7 connections, I'll try to imagine how it looks like!

Comment: @kagaratsch You can replace $7$ with, say, $4$ and $49$ with $16$; lay out marbles $1-16$ on a grid, draw the connections, then lay out $17-32$ on another grid and draw the connections (note that every element in that second grid will have a link directly down to the corresponding element on the first grid), etc etc.

Comment: Oh, but that would mean that to get from first grid to second grid one would have to use a different operation compared to the one that is used to construct each grid itself? (Each slice is constructed as in 2d case, but stacking the slices breaks the pattern.)

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for a homogeneous operation that would construct each slice as well as continue on to the next slice homogeneously, without an observer being able to tell whether an individual slice is completed or not at any step in the process. (like in the 2d case, by rotating the spiraling cylinder in 3d one cannot tell one row from another, they just grow homogeneously.)

Comment: @Kagaratsch It does not; I'm just suggesting looking at individual slices for convenience's sake. Just as you can 'roll' the cylinder, you can roll this grid arbitrarily too; looking at the connections on the 9-24 and 25-40 'slices' will make them appear identical to the 1-16 and 17-32 slices, just as in the 2d case the 1-7 'row' and the 4-10 row 'look' identical.

Comment: I see, I'll really need to imagine this more clearly. Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: Don't be surprised if it's hard to see! Just as you need a 3d cylinder model to really see what's going on in the 2d case, you actually need a sort of 4-dimensional 'stacked donuts' model to see clearly what's going on in the 3d case.

Comment: (@Kagaratsch That said, just as one can 'flatten' the cylinder to a series of nested circles and see some semblance of the 2d grid in that spiral of nested circles, you can do the same thing with nested torii to try and visualize the stacked donuts in 3 dimensions. If I have enough spare time, I may try and do a simple rendering of this for viz purposes, because I'm kind of curious myself...)

Comment: Oh, yeah! A visualization would be super nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

A more usual way to stack the marbles in 2D is 
$$\begin{align} &6\ \ 9\\&3\ \ 5\ \ 8\\&1\ \ 2\ \ 4\ \ 7\end {align}$$, putting a new one on the end and going up diagonally to the left.  The same idea works in any number of dimensions.  In 3D you would place $1,2,3$ as shown, then place $4$ in front of $1$, and continue.

Comment: The issue with this is that there is a disconnect once a diagonal is filled -- this requires two operations instead of just one: 1) stack marbles in diagonal until diagonal is filled. 2) once diagonal is filled, jump back down and start a new diagonal. However, I'd like a stacking that only uses one operation, not two.